# Sitecore caching and varying

Tags: caching, sitecore, vary

This is my first time with Sitecore caching and I haven't been able to find a good guide about how to use the various varying options in Sitecore. I want to know how each is different, how they differ in regards to what they cache and also in what to use in a typical scenario?

Any inputs are appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I wrote this guide a while back, it should give you a pretty good overview: http://learnsitecore.cmsuniverse.net/en/Developers/Articles/2009/07/CachingOverview.aspx

Also Sitecore Australia has this video you might want to watch: http://sitecoreaustralia.wordpress.com/2010/06/28/cache-webinar-recording/

Edit: The above blog seem to have closed. Instead you can download the webinar [here](http://mediacontent.sitecore.net/wmv/CacheRecordingWebinar.mp4)

Cheers
Jens

Comment: http://sitecoreaustralia.wordpress.com/ link is not working.. seems site is removed. Can you provide updated link of the site or video link ?